# Intellij Idea null pointer exception

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, nullpointerexception, editor

I am getting following error in every 10 seconds at idea's output panel while tomcat server is running:

```
    Jul 1, 2013 9:38:35 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor processChildren
SEVERE: Exception invoking periodic operation: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.filterAppPaths(HostConfig.java:527)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:500)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1385)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:306)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1389)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1653)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1662)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1642)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Is there anyone faced this problem before?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look to this: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51654

Comment: Thanks, @StefanBeike , your link has very helped to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is due to missing `appBase` directory in tomcat server.xml. In server.xml,

```
<Host appBase="/path/to/valide/dir/webapps" autoDeploy="false" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true" xmlNamespaceAware="false" xmlValidation="false">
```

`appBase` attribute must be valid directory. It can be absolute path or relative path to `CATALINA_HOME`

There is an issue for this as @Stefan Beike specified above;

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51654

Also you can see documentation for Host config [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/host.html)

Comment: Thank you. it started working even without a restart as soon as I added missing webapps directory.